# Cannot mount external hard disk, MFT records error

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs, partitioning, ntfs-3g

I am trying to mount a Western Digital "My Book" drive, which I used to share between Linux and Windows. It is formatted in NTFS.

When I connect it on Windows, I get the message that the disk is corrupted and cannot be read. In Linux I get the following screenshot:

[image: Hard disk mount]

`sudo fdisk -l`  shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000365289472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243197 cylinders, total 3906963456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x559f69fc

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048  3906963455  1953480704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

And when I try to mount manually, I see this error:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd1 testhd
Run lists overlap. Cannot merge: Numerical result out of range
Run lists overlap. Cannot merge: Numerical result out of range
Failed to calculate free MFT records: Numerical result out of range
```

I already tried `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd1`  and the result is:

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdd1 was processed successfully.
```

But still after this I cannot mount the external drive.

Please help me, I am afraid to lose important data here.

Comment: Not sure what we can do. There is no magic wand for something like this.

Comment: So you mean the hard disk is totally unreadable and there is no possible solution?

Comment: There are no Linux NTFS repair tools. (The poorly-named `ntfsfix` does some *very* basic checks and then marks the disk as needing attention in Windows.) Your best hope is to use a Windows NTFS-repair tool. If you need help with this, I recommend you ask on a Windows forum. If you're desperate, [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) might be able to recover individual files from the disk.

Comment: I have the ask same problem on an NTFS disk, after running udefrag on it. When I switched off my computer yesterday, the disk was mounted without problem. This morning, I'm unable to mount it. I don't have any windows anywhere to fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If it's still of any interest, after more than  one year: I think a

```
chkdsk /f /r  INSERT-HERE-EXT-DRIVELETTER:
```

executed on a Windows machine to check the volume thoroughly could help.. DO NOT let Windows format your drive before you've tried to repair it with `chkdsk`!